# How to create flat tar archive

Tags: gzip, tar

my `tree` command returns

```
tmp
`-- t
    `-- e
        |-- foo.ps
        `-- s
            |-- bar.ps
            `-- t
                `-- baz.ps
```

How can I create archive ps.tar.gz in tmp directory with following structure:

```
tmp
|-- ps.tar.gz
|   |-- foo.ps
|   |-- bar.ps
|   `-- baz.ps
`-- t
    `-- e
        |-- foo.ps
        `-- s
            |-- bar.ps
            `-- t
                `-- baz.ps
```

?

Comment: mkdir archive ; find t/ -name *.ps -exec ln {} archive/ \; ; ( cd archive && tar zcf ../ps.tar.gz *.ps ) ; rm -rf archive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
outfile=$(pwd)/ps.tar;find . -type f | while read file; do 
    tar rf $outfile -C $(dirname $file) $(basename $file)
done
gzip $outfile
```

Comment: If you like to do the above in a oneliner: find . -type f -exec bash -c "archive=./ps.tar.gz;fname=\`basename {}\`;fdir=\`dirname {}\`;tar cfz \$archive -C \$fdir \$fname" \;

Comment: @Qben that should be `tar rf` to append to the archive.   
a) Using `tar cf` will overwrite the output file with the last few files.  
b) Can't append in zipped mode though. So need to do a gzip on the output tar file.

Comment: +1 for a neat script.  
Didn't notice the `$(basename $file)` part being used along with the -C option to help in flattening out the tar file.

Comment: The script above has problem dealing with spaces in the file/dir name. Need to escape the spaces.

Comment: Using fname="${file##*/}" and fdir="${file%/*}" reduces need to shell-out.

Answer (score 13):

for GNU tar you can use the `--xform` argument. It takes a `sed` expression and applies it on each file name. So for removing all characters up to the last `/`, you may use:

```
tar -c --xform s:^.*/:: your-files
```

Comment: Better result for multiple directories can be achieved in combination with http://serverfault.com/a/566345/343194. Something like `find ./commondir -type f | tar --transform 's/.*\///g' -cvzf ./file.tar.gz --files-from=/dev/stdin`. This way empty child directories will be excluded.