# How to create a tar.gz without all the folders

Tags: linux, bash, file, ubuntu, directory

Okay, so what I want to do (in ubuntu server 12.04) is take all the directories in the "servers" folder and create a tar.gz of all of them individually.  For example:
Inside the servers folder are 3 more folders.  Server1, server2 and server3.  I want to compress in a tar.gz the contents of server1, server2, and server3.  So in the server1 folder, I have a test.txt file. I want that to be the only thing inside the server.tar.gz.
Heres the code I have so far in bash

```
servers=(servers/*)
for i in "${servers[@]}"
do
NAME=${i:8} <-- to trim off the /servers/ part of /servers/servernumber
tar -C servers/$NAME/ -cvzf $NAME.tar.gz $NAME
done
```

What ever you can do help would be awesome!

Comment: do you want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4898056/390913

Comment: Do you want to create a single `server.tar.gz` which tars all the files under each of the `server*` directories but should not create individual `server*` directories within the tar file ?

Comment: Perreal - I'm having a hard time understanding what he's asking Essentially I just want to take what's inside /servers/server1/ and those files in there, is all I want in the server1.tar.gz file

Comment: Tuxdude - I want a seperate tar.gz file for each folder inside the servers folder. So server1.tar.gz, server2.tar.gz, server3.tar.gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you wanted to do:

```
for my_dir in servers/server*; do
    tar -C $my_dir -czvf "${my_dir:8}.tar.gz" .
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for dir in servers/*
do
  tar -C $dir -cvzf "$(basename $dir).tar.gz" .
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /path/top
for dir in server1 server2 server3
do
     cd $dir
     tar -cvfz /tmp/${dir}.tar.gz  *
     cd -
done
ls -lrt /tmp/*.tar.gz
```

This seems to be what you want.  Please try it and let us know

Comment: This won't work because the 2nd time through the loop you'll be in the server1 subdirectory, and `cd server2` won't work.