# How to copy only the files of a folder(including subfolder's files), but not the folder itself in shell

Tags: shell, ssh, scp

In Openssh, On the client, the content of path/to/file must be copied to Server. All files in /path/to/file on the client must be copied to /path/to/files on the server. Note: only copy files, no folders! and files of subfolders. please give the command.

Comment: Assuming there are the following files: `dir/foo` `dir/bar` `dir/dir2/random` you want to obtain the files: `foo` `bar` `random` only?

Comment: do you care if 2 files in separate subdirs have the same name? `dira/foo`, `dirb/foo`

Comment: yes.!! mr.glenn. i must think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try the following command:

```
find DIR -type f \
| tar cf - --files-from=- --transform='s+^.*/++' \
| ssh user@hostname 'tar xvf - --directory=DIR'
```

`find` picks the files in directory `DIR`.
Then `tar` creates an on-the-fly archive containing these files and flattens their paths (by removing everything up to the last slash, see [How to create flat tar archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898056/how-to-create-flat-tar-archive)).
Finally `ssh` lets `tar` extract the flat archive on the receiving server into the specified target directory.